# How to add custom prompt or get user input in azure multi-turn QnA Bot Framework V4

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, chatbot

I'm building a bot using Bot Framework V4 in which I used Multiple prompt (Multi-Turn) QnA services.
My requirement is when User reach last question or a specific question, a custom prompt will appear to ask his/her name and store the value in database.
I'm very confuse to how to use dialogs.
Please help me.

**Bot.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Bots
{
    public class QnABot<T> : ActivityHandler where T : Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Dialog
    {
        protected readonly BotState ConversationState;
        protected readonly Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Dialog Dialog;
        protected readonly BotState UserState;

        public QnABot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, T dialog)
        {
            ConversationState = conversationState;
            UserState = userState;
            Dialog = dialog;
        }

        public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
            if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {

            }

            // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
            await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
            await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        }
        private static async Task SendIntroCardAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var card = new HeroCard();
            card.Title = "Hi! I am your personnel Chatbot.";
            card.Text = @"How can I help you today, you can choose from menu and get started.";
            card.Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
            {
            new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "Looking for New Services", value: "selected: Looking for New Services"),
            new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "Looking for Maintenance work", value: "selected: Looking for Maintenance work"),
            new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "Need Technical Support", value: "selected: Need Technical Support"),
            };

            var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment());
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
            // Run the Dialog with the new message Activity.
            await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);

        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await SendIntroCardAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RootDialog.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Dialog
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is an example root dialog. Replace this with your applications.
    /// </summary>
    public class RootDialog : ComponentDialog
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// QnA Maker initial dialog
        /// </summary>
        private const string InitialDialog = "initial-dialog";

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RootDialog"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services">Bot Services.</param>
        public RootDialog(IBotServices services)
            : base("root")
        {
            AddDialog(new QnAMakerBaseDialog(services));

            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(InitialDialog)
               .AddStep(InitialStepAsync));

            // The initial child Dialog to run.
            InitialDialogId = InitialDialog;
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InitialStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(QnAMakerDialog), null, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

**QnAMakerBaseDialog.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Dialog
{
    /// <summary>
    /// QnAMaker action builder class
    /// </summary>
    public class QnAMakerBaseDialog : QnAMakerDialog
    {
        // Dialog Options parameters
        public const string DefaultNoAnswer = "No QnAMaker answers found.";
        public const string DefaultCardTitle = "Did you mean:";
        public const string DefaultCardNoMatchText = "None of the above.";
        public const string DefaultCardNoMatchResponse = "Thanks for the feedback.";

        private readonly IBotServices _services;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="QnAMakerBaseDialog"/> class.
        /// Dialog helper to generate dialogs.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services">Bot Services.</param>
        public QnAMakerBaseDialog(IBotServices services): base()
        {
            this._services = services;
        }

        protected async override Task<IQnAMakerClient> GetQnAMakerClientAsync(DialogContext dc)
        {
            return this._services?.QnAMakerService;
        }

        protected override Task<QnAMakerOptions> GetQnAMakerOptionsAsync(DialogContext dc)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new QnAMakerOptions
            {
                ScoreThreshold = DefaultThreshold,
                Top = DefaultTopN,
                QnAId = 0,
                RankerType = "Default",
                IsTest = false
            });
        }

        protected async override Task<QnADialogResponseOptions> GetQnAResponseOptionsAsync(DialogContext dc)
        {
            var noAnswer = (Activity)Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
            noAnswer.Text = DefaultNoAnswer;

            var cardNoMatchResponse = (Activity)MessageFactory.Text(DefaultCardNoMatchResponse);


            var responseOptions = new QnADialogResponseOptions
            {
                ActiveLearningCardTitle = DefaultCardTitle,
                CardNoMatchText = DefaultCardNoMatchText,
                NoAnswer = noAnswer,
                CardNoMatchResponse = cardNoMatchResponse,
            };

            return responseOptions;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-primitive-prompts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) documentation where it specifies how to create your own prompts to gather user input. A conversation between a bot and a user often involves asking (prompting) the user for information, parsing the user's response, and then acting on that information.

The documentation is based on sample [44.prompt-users-for-input](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/44.prompt-users-for-input).
The bot maintains conversation state to track and direct the conversation and ask the user questions. The bot maintains user state to track the user's answers.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I also see this example but can't find a way to integrate with Multi-Turn QnA maker.

Comment: what are you stuck at when you tried the sample? we also have an [experimental sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/70.qnamaker-multiturn-sample) if you'd like to take a look

Comment: Yes i would like to know how to integrate this code with Authentication example. Can someone help?

Comment: Hi Safi. Did you find a solution to this?